# Is there a way to detect wether text fits in a button/label and reduce font size until it fits?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am currently using `wraplength = bDict[b].winfo_width()-8` to wrap my text so it fits inside the button / label. This works great so long as everything fits in the window but if it doesn't it just pushes the text out the top and bottom of the window. In an effort to avoid this being a problem I am trying to find a way to dynamically reduce the font size in order to allow the text to fit. To make that work I am hoping there is a way for me to detect if the text fits in a label. The UI I am working on is dynamically scalable so when the window is too small it doesn't leave enough room for the text in some of the labels.